# PHP file_get_contents returning 404 with a URL on the local server

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, file-get-contents

We have an amazon ec2 instance with apache running and several websites. When trying to run file_get_contents on a URL from say website A to website B, it fails returning a default 404 error page. When we try to file_get_contents any remote, external website it succeeds.

I have rewritten the code using stream_context_create to run the requests through a proxy. When that is done, it does successfully pull the content in however the speed is a major issue.

Ideally, I want to make it so file_get_contents works on URL's on the local server without having to run it through a proxy.

I have google'd for a few hours today to find a solution, i've already tried numerous suggestions but i'm having no luck.

Does anybody have any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using just curl in command line to see if perhaps the EC2 IP range has been blocked? Depending on the their server handles it they may simply return a 404 instead of 403 Forbidden.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, i've tried CURL too, still the same issue, whenever I output the contents, its the 404 error page.

Comment: So if you can access it from a difference machine and you are sure that there aren't any service/server differences other than IP address chances are they may have taken action to prevent scraping from Amazon's network (there are plenty of misbehaving bots/crawlers/spiders out there).

Comment: Thanks, but surely that would result in a failure of file_get_contents with a corresponding error message? Instead, im getting a 404 page from the website.